# How do I return a string that builds a new table row each time a function is called in PHP?

Tags: php, string, function, return

I have created a function in PHP that is supposed to "return a string that builds a new table row each time it is called" . I've tried searching for how to do this but I'm unsure. Can anyone provide assistance ? My code for the function that I built is below:

```
<?php
//Creating the function returnRow().
function returnRow($counter, $quantity) 
{
    $ticketprice = 50;

    if($quantity >= 300)
    {
        $ticketprice = 30;
    }
    else if ($quantity >= 200)
    {
        $ticketprice = 35;
    }
    else if ($quantity < 200)
    {
        $ticketprice = 50;
    }

    //The return statement will go here but I do not know how to create it.
   //it will return a new html table row.
}

?>
```

Comment: `return $ticketprice;`

Comment: What you have here does not return anything other than a string, nothing about a table row.

Comment: A table row in what? HTML? SQL?

Comment: A table row in HTML

Comment: First add the return statement to your function. Right now it is not returning anything. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated how many columns are in this table but literally just return the HTML string you want:

```
<?php
//Creating the function returnRow().
function returnRow($counter, $quantity) 
{
    $ticketprice = 50;

    if($quantity >= 300)
    {
        $ticketprice = 30;
    }
    else if ($quantity >= 200)
    {
        $ticketprice = 35;
    }
    else if ($quantity < 200)
    {
        $ticketprice = 50;
    }
//Example, I don't know what columns are actually present
   return "<tr><td>{$quantity}</td><td>{$ticketprice}</td></tr>";

}

?>
```

Comment: I didn't think the number of columns was necessary, just the syntax to return the table rows. That solved the problem though, thanks!

Comment: It's necessary if you plan on having a well-formatted HTML table but it sounds like this was a homework question anyways, joke's on me

Comment: It will be formatted, I will create the columns using a loop with a counter variable for the number of columns. I just needed clarification on how to return the table rows. Much appreciated!